# Why don't work on the device and work on the simulator?

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-sqlite

I'm making an app that access a mysql DB. I'm using direct JDBC, not web service. The simulator access with no problem but the real device give the error

`The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.`

This is the code of the connection class (its only the connection method)

```
public static Connection CONN(String name) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    Connection conn = null;
    String ConnURL = null;
    try {

        Class.forName(classs);

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, un, password);


        String stsql = "Select version()";


        Toaster.toast(name);


        //conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        Log.e("ERRO", se.getMessage());
        Toaster.toast(se.getMessage());
        System.out.println( se.getMessage() );
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
    }
    return conn;
}
```

Can someone gives me some help?
Thanks!

Comment: @ Zauberer what is the url string?It must contain your Machine's IP address instead of localhost.

Comment: static String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.11:3306/test";  this is. i tried turning off the firewall, using the url asigned to the device, using the url asigned to mysql and nothing works. but the emulator works.i never used localhost

Comment: is your machine and mobile is in same network?

Comment: yes. is the same network. i use the ip read in the mysql administrator. Thanks!